# The Presets on Blocks isn't showing up until i manually add it in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have added presets inside blocks in Shopify in order to have 2 presets by default when i open the Customizer. But the presets aren't showing up unless i add them manually

I tried looking at Shopify's documentation but still no luck the presets do not appear.

```
<div id="section-cta">
<div class="section-header text-center">
<h3>{{section.settings.text-box}}</h3>
</div>

{% for block in section.blocks %}
<div class="btn btn-primary">
<a href="{{block.settings.link}}" class="btn btn-primary"> 
{{block.settings.linktext}}</a>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
{% schema %}
{
"name": "CTA Blocks",
"max_blocks" : 3,
"settings": [
{
  "id" : "text-box",
  "type" : "text",
  "label" : "Heading",
  "default" : "Title"
}
],
"blocks":[
{
"type" : "select",
"name" : "select",
"settings" : [
{
  "id" : "link",
  "type" : "url",
  "label" : "Button Link"
},
{
  "id" : "linktext",
  "type" : "text",
  "label" : "Button Here",
  "default" : "Click Here"
}
]
}

],
"presets" : [
{
  "name" : "Call to Action Blocks",
  "category" : "Call to Action Button",
  "blocks": [
  {
    "type" : "select"
  },
  {
    "type" : "select"
  }
]
  }
]
}
{% endschema %}
```

So here is the image for it

[image]

There should have been 2 Add Button automatically right?

Answer (score 1):

Presets are a part of Schema not the block. Moreover, **Presets** are not used to add content. From the [Shopify Docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#static-and-dynamic-sections)

> Sections can be dynamically added to the theme's home page if they
>   have presets defined in their respective {% schema %} tags. Sections
>   with presets will automatically be accessible in the theme editor.

They are used to create Dynamic sections.

> Section presets are default configurations of a section. They are not
>   related to the theme styles that are defined in settings_data.json.
>   When a section has one or more presets, each preset becomes a dynamic
>   section a merchant can add to their theme home page if the
>   content_for_index object has been included in index.liquid.

[Shopify Preset Docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#presets)

Comment: As you can see above in my code i already have added a preset that contains 2 blocks but still it isnt showing up when i load the site

Comment: @MaddoxSt that is what I have mentioned in my answer. Adding preset will give you an option to add those blocks on homepage. By add I mean, you will be able to add them on homepage via customizer. Presets will not add any content automatically.

Comment: Oh i get it now and what do i have to do so that i can have 2 presets be there when the site is loaded via the customizer.
As per the example i have given what should i do to already have the Link Text and Text box when i click the block?

Comment: @MaddoxSt I don't know any documented way. That data is stored in settings_data.json file. May be add it to that..