# Shopify section schema: different content for each present block

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm just starting out with Shopify development, and I'm creating a custom section called **USP Banner** which has a single block type called `column` that can be added up to 4 times; and that column just has one `text` and one `richtext` field within it. The content of each column is identical on every page, but the section can appear in different places depending on the page itself.

I've given the `column` default values for the `text` & `richtext` and added the 4 columns that will be used into the `presets` definition of the schema; however because it's just the same column x 4, each column has the same content 4 times. What I'm aiming for is that when you add the section to any page, it prefills each column with different content.

I read through the Shopify docs and all I found was some vague allusion to having a `settings` object within the block presets, but I can't find any examples of that anywhere. I also found [an old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56989730/988246) stating that `presets` can't contain default content.

Is there an easy way to add default content to repeating blocks within a section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not made clear in the [official docs](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#presets), you *can* set default values for repeated blocks in the presets; but whereas the `settings` when defining the blocks are arrays of objects, the `settings` within the `preset` blocks are **objects** where each pre-determined field value uses the field's unique ID as its key. For example, a typical section schema might look like:

```
{% schema %}
    {
        "name": "USP Banner",
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "column",
                "name": "Column",
                "limit": 4,
                "settings": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "id": "heading",
                        "label": "Heading",
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "richtext",
                        "id": "text",
                        "label": "Text",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "presets": [
            {
                "name": "USP Banner",
                "blocks": [
                    {
                        "type": "column"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "column"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
{% endschema %}
```

...so to create preset values for each block, we simply add `settings` to the `preset` definition like so:

```
"presets": [
    {
        "name": "USP Banner",
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "column",
                "settings": {
                    "heading": "Remarkable Value",
                    "text": "<p>Never knowingly undersold</p>"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "column",
                "settings": {
                    "heading": "5-Year Warranty",
                    "text": "<p>We're that confident in our products</p>"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

...where the key for each field (`heading` & `text` in this case) is the ID of the defined fields in the `blocks` section at the top of the schema.